# What was this building and what happend to it?

Tags: identification, building

I recently visited Lofoten in Norway and in small village called Myrland there was a building of some sort near the beach. It looked like docks. It was protected by the sea wall that was build from massive stone block held together by massive iron rods. It was and breached in the middle. Here is photo of the wall.[image]

My question is what was this structure and what happened to the wall. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that this is it.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing ... It could be the foundations/support level of a former [fishermen's cabin](https://www.switchbacktravel.com/norway/lofoten-islands/rorbuer), as seen to the bottom right of the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Maybe, but the stones in OP's picture are well-worked and regular, and the cabin foundations aren't.